# How do smooth manifolds differ from manifolds embedded in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Tags: differential-topology

Instead of defining a smooth manifold to be a manifold whose gluing functions are smooth, what would happen if we defined it as an $n$-manifold $M$ which has an embedding into $\mathbb{R}^{n +1}$?

A smooth map between manifolds $e_M : M \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and $e_N : N \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ would be a continuous function $f : M \to N$ along with a smooth function $g : \mathbb{R}^{n+1} \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ such that $g \circ e_M = e_N \circ f$.

Would defining them this way be equivalent?

Comment: No. The real projective plane wouldn’t be a smooth manifold, because there are no embeddings into $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: Definitely not equivalent, because not all topological manifolds admit a smooth structure, but all topological manifolds embed in $\Bbb R^n$ for large enough $n$.

Comment: The definition presented here is certainly not equivalent, though it's worth noting there *is* a way to equivalently define a smooth manifold as a "sufficiently nice" subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$, due to the [Whitney embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_embedding_theorem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start, the Klein bottle would no longer be a smooth manifold, as it has no embedding in $\Bbb R^3$. Nor would any non-orientable closed $2$-manifold.